# PHP laravel error al guardar un array me sale FatalErrorException in InvoiceController.php line 35: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Tags: php

```
{
$customers=new Customer;
$customers->firstname=$request->fn;
$customers->lastname=$request->ln;
$customers->sex=$request->sex;
$customers->email=$request->email;
$customers->phone=$request->phone;
$customers->location=$request->location;
$id = $customers->save();

if ($id !=0){
foreach ($request->productname as $key => $v) 
{
$data =array('cus_id'=>$id,
               'pro_id'=>$v,
                'qty'=>$request->qty [$key],
                 'price'=>$request->price [$key],
                  'dis'=>$request->dis [$key],
                   'amount'=>$request->amount [$key]);
Sale::insert($data);


}


}
```